# Maps of $S^1$ to $S^1$ by taking integer powers that are homotopic to a homeomorphism

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Let $g_k:S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ be defined by $z \mapsto z^k$, sending a complex number $z$ of norm 1 to its $k$-th power, where $k$ is an integer.

Question: For which $k$ is the map $g_k$ homotopic to a homeomorphism?

My immediate thought is that the only homeomorphism will be where $k=2n\pi$, since any other $k$ will make it such that at least a point is hit more than once, so it won't be surjective. I do not, however, know how to show if this is true for homotopy to homeomorphism. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Your post says that $k$ is an integer, so your immediate thought does not make much sense. Do you know about the degree of a map $S^{n} \to S^{n}$?

Comment: ah yes I see it, it doen't make sense. Yes, I do know about the degree of a map from $S^n \rightarrow S^n$

Comment: it is the number that is multiplied my in the induced homomorphism on fundamental groups

Comment: To show a map is homemorphisim is easy if the space is compact and hausdorf you only. Need to show it's bijective

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an outline of an approach; some details I leave to you.

$1)$ Show that the degree of the map $g_{k}$ is $k$.

$2)$ Show that the degree of a homeomorphism is $\pm 1$ (there are many approaches here, but one you might use is that degree is multiplicative across composition, and the identity map has degree $1$).

$3)$ Recall that the degrees of two homotopic maps are equal; conclude that we must have $k = \pm 1$.

$4)$ Note that if $k = 1$ or $k = -1$, then $g_{k}$ is actually a homeomorphism; if $k = 1$, this is immediate. If $k = -1$, you can observe that $g_{k}$ is an involution.